# If in Javascript Setter

Tags: javascript

I tried to create class in Javascript and wanted to set the parameter in specific format. For example, the class Person will only accept Age parameter in number format. If not, the if statement will return "Please type age in number format".

Below is my code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }

    set age(value) {
        if (value.isNaN()) {
            console.log('Please type age in number format');
        } else {
            this._age = value;
        }
    }
}

const bill = new Person('bill', 'twenty');
console.log(bill.age)
```

I expect the code will return "please type age in number format". However the code returns 'twenty'. Kindly help.

Comment: Your constructor has `this._age = age` so you never even invoke the setter.

Comment: When you use new to initalize an object of a class, it will trigger the constructor.

Comment: After you're really "calling" the setter, there's another problem. `isNaN` is not a property of String, it's a global function. You've to pass `value` as an argument to `isNaN` instead of calling it as a method.

Comment: @Aplet123 can you please explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. In your constructor you are setting `this._age = age;` so you never call the `get/set` of the property `age` To do this you can replace that part of the code:

```
constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        // You must call this.age to fire the setter
        this.age = age;
    }
```

If you see, I only change `this.age = age;` and not the `this.name = name;` because the property `name` doesn't have a setter, only has a getter.

2. The validation in the setter of age will cause errors when the parameter is not a Number to fix that you must do:

```
if (typeof value !== "number" || !isFinite(value)) {
```

The first problem is `value.isNaN()` function don't exists, must do `isNaN(value)` or `Number.isNaN(value)`

The second, in that context I can pass you the values `Infinity`, so you could replace with `not finite values` and catch all the `NaN` and `Infinity` values.

Answer (score 0):

Agree to [@Aplet123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5923139/aplet123), since constructor has `this._age = age` so you never even invoke the setter.

If you want/expect the code to return "please type age in number format", you may modify code as,

```
...
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        if (value.isNaN()) {
            console.log('Please type age in number format');
        } else {
            this._age = value;
        }
    }
```

This will not set the value for `_age` and if you try to access it using your object created ( of this class), you will get `undefined`.